# Aptana Git plugin standalone

Tags: eclipse, git, aptana, egit

I have looked at the Aptana 3 git support and I found it much better than EGit. Especially because it does not use JGit (buggy, missing features) and is integrates with git installed in my OS. Is there any way how to use just this Aptana Git plugin in Eclipse without installing the whole Aptana studio? (We develop in Java and do not need Aptana studio.)

I have tried to copy some stuff from Aptana plugins directory, but had no luck. I know Aptana is open source, but I have no Eclipse plugin development skills and I do not know how deep is Aptana Git sources integrated into the rest of Aptana studio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't currently break our Git support out as a separate feature. It is contained to two plugins, but they rely on a handful of the core aptana plugins. Unfortunately the best answer is to just install Aptana's plugin for Eclipse. It would take some development effort to break the dependencies so that just the git support could be installed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Christopher.